# How to create a joint, where the rotation of one object is relative to the other?

Tags: c++, rotation, box2d, joints

I would like to create a top down view scene, with one rectangle (`top`) is on top of an other (`base`). There is a joint, where these two objects are connected.

The one on the top should be able to freely rotate, but if the base rotates, its rotation should be changed as well, because it should behave as if it is on top of it. If the joint is at the center of both objects, then the top one should rotate like this:

```
Δ top rotation = Δ time * ( top angular velocity + base angular velocity )
```

If the joint is not at the center of the objects, then it is more complicated than that. How is it possible to define a joint like that in Box2D?

This is a testbed example with the joint. Notice, that the top one is not rotating:

```cpp
#include "test.h"

class RelJoint : public Test
{

    b2Body* base;
    b2Body* top;
    b2RevoluteJoint* m_joint;

public:

    RelJoint() {

        m_world->SetGravity(b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f));

        {

            b2PolygonShape shape;
            shape.SetAsBox(1.f, 0.5f, b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f), 0.0f);

            b2BodyDef bd;
            bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
            b2Body* body = m_world->CreateBody(&bd);
            body->CreateFixture(&shape, 5.0f);

            body->SetAngularDamping(1.f);

            base = body;
        }

        {

            b2PolygonShape shape;
            shape.SetAsBox(0.5f, 0.25f, b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f), 0.0f);

            b2BodyDef bd;
            bd.type = b2_dynamicBody;
            b2Body* body = m_world->CreateBody(&bd);
            body->CreateFixture(&shape, 5.0f);

            top = body;
        }

        b2RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef;
        revoluteJointDef.bodyA = base;
        revoluteJointDef.bodyB = top;
        revoluteJointDef.collideConnected = false;

        revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set(0, 0);
        revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set(0, 0);

        m_joint = (b2RevoluteJoint*)m_world->CreateJoint(&revoluteJointDef);

    }

    void Step(Settings& settings) override {
        base->ApplyTorque(3.f, true);

        Test::Step(settings);
    }

    static Test* Create()
    {
        return new RelJoint;
    }

};

static int testIndex = RegisterTest("Joints", "Relative", RelJoint::Create);
```

---

I tried to combine `b2RevoluteJointDef` with `b2FrictionJointDef`. It looks promising, but unfortunately if I apply torque to the top body only, the base starts to rotate too, which I would like to avoid.